# JAVA to access a php file - something similar to HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: java, php

I'm on apache server and use a PHP HTTP_REFERER just to check that a few clients are accessing from pre-determined URLS. I have someone inquiring about accessing from a JAVA application. I know nothing about JAVA and I'm trying to find an alternative way to recognize the referring location accessing my php files. (I've also used an .htaccess with HTTP_REFERER in the past but again not for JAVA trying to gain access).

This doesn't need to be a complex "fort knox" solution because I know HTTP_REFERER isn't that in the first place, I just don't want the link being passed around freely in the wild.

?

Comment: password protect the url. don't depend on the referer.

Comment: Referrer has nothing to do with `PHP` and everything to do with `HTTP`.

Comment: This sounds like the same problem any API has. How about giving out access keys to all those that *use* your application & validate the key in your app? Leverage $_GET?

Comment: Trying to avoid his users having to login a second time on my side.

Comment: I've considered the access Key option and as the answer below also touches on... the trust issue. it's a professional relationship, but people may come and go over time etc. I like to give credit to both suggestions as valid options, was just hoping for another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question depends on what HTTP library your client is using to access your stuff from Java.  A decent HTTP client library (e.g. Apache [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)) will let you set arbitrary headers.  See for example http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html.

Comment: I'm supposed to follow up with them next week and was trying to prep for the call so I will share this and go from there. Thanks...going to check this off and the other solution as valid answers

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't want the link being passed around freely in the wild.

Why not setup an API access via a key that is passed via the URL?

Example:

> mypage.php?key=hjuedh78923hjhbdjb990823908bnhdjhh20JHGSdjla

Then check $_GET['key'] to make sure that it is a valid registered key.

Of course, this method rests on whether or not you trust those with the Java application.

Comment: that may be the way I need to go. maybe just periodically notify them I'm updating the Key

Comment: Thanks! This is a valid solution apparently I just can't check both off